# Microsoft Office Icons - At Least 500 x 500

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, print-design, resolution

Anybody know where there are some Microsoft Office Icons that are at least 500 x 500 pixels wide and a good resolution to download? I might even be willing to pay for them, I just don't want to have to make them all, gag.

Any help would be appreciated.

If you don't know of anywhere to get them, any tips on making them?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Finding icon sets is a task best suited to your search engine of choice.  As for "tips on making them", that's entirely dependent on the purpose of the icons.  Can you be more specific about what you've tried or why icons you've found don't suit your needs?

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I agree that this is better suited to the search engine of my choice, however such efforts have long since been exhausted. The answers below provide much more helpful information for me, such as why I cannot find anything larger than 256x256, which was very helpful. As for what I intend to do with them, I need to make a large banner with them on it for a back lit booth banner, so they needed to look good at about a foot tall. As for OS X versions, the boss won't take em. Thanks for all your help guys, check goes to most helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One tip I can give you is if you want that size - which is larger than the 256x256 maximum for Windows 7 icons - you should be looking at vector art that can be scaled to any output size without loss of resolution, rather than fixed-resolution raster images.

Answer (score 2):

Is you can use the OS X versions, then you might be able to get a 512×512 or 1024×1024 sized icon, as those are standard on the Mac. 1024×1024 is fairly new, but I'd guess that Microsoft's icons *should* be 512×512.

Having said that, I noticed an Adobe OS X icon that's 128×128 a couple of days ago...